# Accessing dictionary objects in python and json

Tags: python-3.x

How to identify each object in the dict.  I am expecting expecting first and last of the entries.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json


with open("test_data.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

for each in data:
        print(each[0]["traits"][0]["disease"])
        print(each[1]["traits"][1]["disease"])

print(data)
```

JSON

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "del aut",
    "completed": false,
    "traits": [
        {"bodypart": "head", "disease": "headache"},
        {"bodypart": "chest", "disease": "asthma"}
        ],


    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "wokey",
    "completed": true,
    "traits": [
        {"bodypart": "cns", "disease": "nuropathy"},
        {"bodypart": "bone", "disease": "artheritis"}
        ]
}
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./seer.core.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(each[0]["traits"][1]["disease"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

print Json

```
print(data) 
{'userId': 2, 'id': 2, 'name': 'wokey', 'completed': True, 'traits': [{'bodypart': 'cns', 'disease': 'nuropathy'}, {'bodypart': 'bone', 'disease': 'artheritis'}]}
```

Comment: You are iterating over keys of a dictionary (i.e. the `for each in data`) and accessing indices of the key's value. But not all keys have lists as its values. Maybe check if the key is named "traits" before accessing its values.

Comment: When I `print(data)` it only prints the last entry of json.

Comment: That json is pretty broken. It looks like it is missing `[...},{...]`, where the middle part goes to the two empty lines.

Comment: json is fine. `print(data)` gives `{'userId': 2, 'id': 2, 'name': 'wokey', 'completed': True, 'traits': [{'bodypart': 'cns', 'disease': 'nuropathy'}, {'bodypart': 'bone', 'disease': 'artheritis'}]}
`

Comment: Just because you can print the `data` object doesn't mean it is valid `JSON` syntax. That is _NOT_ valid `JSON` syntax.

Comment: import json


with open("json.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)


for k, v in data.items():
    if(k=='traits'):
        for i in v:
            print(i['bodypart']),print(i['disease'])

Comment: It only prints the last entry because you are reusing the keys.

Answer (score 2):

```html
import json


with open("json.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)


for k, v in data.items():
    if(k=='traits'):
        for i in v:
            print(i['bodypart']),print(i['disease'])
```

[image]